# Dynamo DB run multiple queries for list of HasKey but without range key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I have a table which has a HashKey defined and there can be multiple records corresponding to this. So, I have a range key which helps in uniquely determining the record.

I want to query all records for a given HashKey and for this I am using the DynamoDBQuery. This works as expected. Now, I have to query for list of HashKey's. So, I run the query as many times as there are HasKeys, collate the result and send back.

I came across batchLoad where-in we can specify list of KeyPair and that returns result for each of KeyPair. My understanding is, for batch load, each KeyPair should uniquely identify the record and hence should have both Hash+Range key.

In my case, I don't have an range key but a List of HashKeys only, what are options to query the DB apart from having multiple queries? Is there any faster approach or is this the efficient one?

Thanks!

Comment: I could do this, as your question is very old, please let me know if you still seek help.

Comment: @NewUser I am looking the answer of this. If you have any solution then let me know.